# Linking error when Calling a C header file

Tags: c++, c, qt, linker, extern

I am calling a C function from a header file I wrote in Qt written in Cpp. I keep getting a linking error when I try to compile my Qt Application.

here is the header file:

```
#ifndef GROUND_SERVER_H
#define GROUND_SERVER_H


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct system_info{
    char id[33];
};

/*  Support function for the below function */
    void Generate_Key(char*,char*,char*);

/*  Runs the actual key generation as well as 
    moves the file to the respectful card or
    USB drive inserted in the system that will
    act as the user system key  */ 
void run_key_generation(struct system_info*,char*,char*);

/*  Function to run the server on a selected 
    port at which the medium that the server 
    is to listen on will be connected.  */
void run_server(unsigned short);

void generate_id();

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif


#endif
```

Comment: Right now I am simply including the header in my Qt project and then trying to call the generate_id() function..

Comment: What's the error exactly?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_generate_id", referenced from:
      MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Ground_Control.app/Contents/MacOS/Ground_Control] Error 1
12:32:46: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Ground_Control (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

@AdiLevin

Comment: Eh ... *are* you linking against the object files (or library) containing the definitions of these functions?

Comment: @DanielJour all I'm doing is just #include "/PATH/Ground_Server.h"

Comment: @JakeBrown You need to also compile the file(s) with the function definitions (presumably `Ground_Server.c`) which will yield a object file (e.g. `Ground_Server.o`) which you need to add to the linking phase of your build.

Comment: So I can make the .o files when i compile "gcc -c Ground_Server.c" but will it not have to be done with g++ and if so then I will get a bunch of errors because I am using strlen in my c code... as well as other c specific functions. @DanielJour

Comment: "c specific functions" do not exist, they're just functions from the c standard library, compiled as every other function and thus accessible from any code linking against them (and using the correct calling convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include "foo.h"` is only the textual inclusion of the contents of `foo.h` into the current compilation unit. If you implement a function in a different file, then you need to compile that file, too, and link the resulting object files to form an executable (or library).

This does also apply when mixing C and C++ (or most other compiled) code: You compile the source code files with the compiler suitable for the language they're written in, and finally link everything together.

So:

#### foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H 1
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int answer(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

### foo.c

```
int answer(void) {
  return 42;
}
```

### bar.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  std::cout << "The answer is " << answer() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

To create an executable from these files, you need to:

```
gcc -c foo.c   # Compile C file
g++ -c bar.cc  # Compile C++ file
g++ -o foobar foo.o bar.o # Link
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I went through and added the object files to the .pro file in QT and seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the example! @DanielJour